# C# working with text files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, text-files

I've been working on this for hours I'm to the last piece of what I'm working on. I need to figure out how restrict the loop to take values from a defined rang on text lines. Like lines 1-5, then 6-10, etc.

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader("values.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a <= 5; a++)
            {
                line = tr.ReadLine();
                **while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)**
                    for (a = 0; a <= 5; a++){
                        ln = tr.ReadLine();
                        if (ln != null){
                            value = int.Parse(ln);
                            if (value > max)
                                max = value;
                            if (value < min)
                                min = value;}
                    }
                Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadLine());
                if (i % 5 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("The max is" + max);
                if (i % 5 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("The min is" + min);
                if (i % 5 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("-----First 5");
            }
```

I'm ready to go to bed but don't want to sleep defeated. Any push in the right way would be appreciated.

Comment: I can see many mistakes in your code...1) Your inner for loop is changing the outer for loop's variable `a`. 2) The 3 `if` conditions are same. About your requirement: you can do as suggested by `Jamiec`

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this easily using LINQ's `Skip`<sup>[docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx)</sup> and `Take`<sup>[docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)</sup> methods. Just read in your text using `File.ReadAllLines`<sup>[docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)</sup> then Skip and Take as necessary:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("values.txt").Skip(5).Take(5);
//lines now has lines 6-10
```

If you're doing this multiple times, I would suggest splitting this up into the file access, and the linq:

```
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines("values.txt")
var lines6To10 = allLines.Skip(5).Take(5);

... // Later on 

var lines21To25 = allLines.Skip(20).Take(5)
```

As for the rest of your code.. looks like you're trying to find the min/max from the lines, which should only contain integers.

```
var min = int.MaxValue;
var max = int.MinValue;
foreach(var line in lines)
{
   var value = int.Parse(line);
   if(value > max)
      max = value;
   if(value < min)
      min = value;
}
```

This can be seen in the line example: http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=SHP19181 (Note the different way of loading the numbers, as rextester cant load from a file. The principle is the same though)

Comment: for multiple calls I would first read all lines and save them in a list<string> and then use linq Skip and Take - so you don't have so much file operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `StreamReader` (e.g. because  file size is expected to be large) you can do it like this:

```
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader("values.txt"))
{
    string currentLine = null;

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("processing set of 5 lines");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            currentLine = tr.ReadLine();
            if (currentLine == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("processing line {0} of 5", i);
            // your code goes here:
        }

    } while (currentLine != null);
}
```

**Edit:** And you should use your StreamReader inside a `using block` (code updated).

Comment: Thats fine for lines 0 to 5, but how would OP process lines `x` to `y`. Say lines 20 - 25.

Comment: @Jamiec: Well, the OP asked for a "defined rang on text lines", which is addressed better by your answer. **But** he also asked for "_Like lines 1-5, then 6-10, etc_" which can be achieved perfectly well with the `StreamReader` approach.